# jquery remove blinking

Tags: jquery, hover, blink

Block is blinking on `.hover()`

Here is a **full example** - http://jsfiddle.net/xBEjQ/

**How to fix this?**

**UPD:** popup should be removed *after the mouse leaved the smaller block* (`.image`), not `.popup` block.

Comment: You can't do it on mouseout of the smaller block, since you're on a layer above it...not without the blinking you're getting now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*For updated Question:* Since the mouse events won't occur on that smaller element (it's completely overlapped) you'd have to use a *third* `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="popup"></div>
    <div class="popup upper"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

And add this CSS (note the higher `z-index` than the other `.popup`):

```
.upper { width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 41; }
```

and script to match:

```
$(".block .image").mouseenter(function(){
    console.log($(this).siblings(".popup").length);
  $(this).siblings(".popup").show();
});
$(".block .upper").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".popup").andSelf().hide();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eQ8EJ/1/).

---

*For previous question:* Since the popup is over top of the element, use the [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) on the trigger, [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) on the popup, like this:

```
$(".block .image").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".popup").show();
});
$(".block .popup").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eQ8EJ/).

Comment: @Happy - what you want's not possible there, since you won't get any mouse events on the element being overlapped completely.  You'd either need a third transparent div of the same size above the popup (messy) or use `mouseleave` on the popup, which I have above.

Comment: can you give example with transparent div? seems to be a solution

Comment: @Happy - I just updated with a demo of how to do this, take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xBEjQ/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="popup"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".block .image").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".popup").show();
});

$(".block .popup").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.block { position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px; background: #ccc; }
.popup { display: none;
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #eee; z-index: 40; }
.image { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #aaa; z-index: 30;
```

Comment: Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for cases like this (like `.hover()` does), since `mouseover` and `mouseout` will fire when entering children as well. For example if there were any elements in the popup (there probably will be), it'll hide when the mouse moves onto any of them.

Comment: @Nick Craver Thanks for explaining that for me. I always enjoy reading your answers. I was wondering why there were both mouseout and mouseenter. I'll leave this answer up for anyone else who might not know that already. :D

Answer (score 1):

show the popup on mouseover
hide the popup on mouseout **of the popover**

http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/WkH6q/

Comment: Again don't use `mouseout` here, see my comment on @tinifni's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".block .image").mouseover(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".popup").show();
    }
);
$(".block .popup").mouseout(
    function(){
        $(this).hide();
    }
);
```

This only applies if you have the "popup" over top of the "image". The reason it's blinking is because as soon as the "popup" shows it's triggering the "mouseout" on the "image" and thus hiding the "popup"

Your code will work fine as long as the "popup" isn't positioned over top of the "image".